# How to add the preface to Contents in ConTeXt?

Tags: table-of-contents, context

I am writing an aritcle on English grammar which has a preface in the front matter. Now I found that the preface wasn't added to contents. I try to redefine the combinedlist, but it still has no effect.

```
\definecombinedlist
  [content]
  [part,chapter,
   title,
   section,subsection,
   subsubsection,subsubsubsection]
\starttext
\setuppagenumbering
  [alternative=dobulesided]

\startfrontmatter
\completecontent
\title{Preface}
Two years ago, I met $\ldots$
\stopfrontmatter

\startbodymatter
\chapter{Phrasal verb}
The term {\bf phrasal verb} is commonly applied to two or three distinct but related constructions in English.
\stopbodymatter
\stoptext
```

How can I define the combinedlist so that it can contain the preface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add the unnumbered elements to the table of contents, you need to set
`incrementnumber` to `list`:

```
\setuphead
  [title]
  [incrementnumber=list]
```

This, however, lists the table of contents in the table of contents,
which is usually not desired. One solution is to use `\placecontent`
instead of `\completecontent` to prevent automatic placement of the
head, then create a manual head with `\starttitle` and disable
saving it into the table of content using `saveinlist=no`. Here's a full
example:

```
\definecombinedlist
  [content]
  [title, chapter]

\setuphead
  [title]
  [incrementnumber=list]

\starttext
  \starttitle [title=Contents, saveinlist=no]
    \placecontent
  \stoptitle
  \starttitle [title=Preface]
  \stoptitle
  \startchapter [title=Phrasal verb]
  \stopchapter
\stoptext
```

Comment: by the way, can I look up the default values of margin, width and distance in the chapter, section list?

Comment: See the definitions in file [strc-def.mkiv](https://gitorious.org/context/context/blobs/origin/tex/context/base/strc-def.mkiv).